# Non-repeating sets of 6 random numbers using only loops

Tags: c, loops

Can you help me with this. I'm having trouble conceptualizing this. Also he requires global declarations

> For this project you are tasked with building a user application that will select sets of random numbers. Your application must use functions and pass values. Your program will pick sets of 6 random numbers with values of 1 to 53. The user should be able to choose how many sets to produce. The challenge will be to ensure that no number in a set of 6 is a repeat. Your program should prompt the user and ask them how many number sets they wish to have. This could be used as a lottery ticket quick pick application. For those who do not condone gambling, it could just be a tool to select random numbers for a game of fun.

This is before the array lesson. I am *only* supposed to use loops and `srand((time(NULL))`. **No arrays or shuffle functions.**

So I was thinking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define FIRST 1
#define LAST 53
#define COUNT 6

int PrintIns(void)
{
  printf("******************************************************************\n");
  printf("Enter the amount of sets of 6 random numbers you want to generate.\n");
  printf("Enter in 'q' or 'Q' to quit...\n");
  printf("******************************************************************\n");
}


int PrintRand(int FIRST, int LAST, int COUNT) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) { 
        int num = (rand() % 
        (FIRST - LAST + 1)) + LAST; 
        printf("%d ", num); 
    return num;
    } 
} 


int main(void){
  int numSets = -99;
  srand(time(NULL));
  int runningSetCount = -99;
  int i;
  int num;
  int exit;
  {
    do{
      PrintIns();
      scanf("%d" , &numSets);
      if(numSets == 81)
        {
          break;
        }
      else if(numSets == 113)
        {
          break;
        }
        else{
          runningSetCount = 1;
          for(i=runningSetCount; i<=numSets; i++)
          {
            printf("**Set Number %3d of six numbers:   %3d\n" , runningSetCount, PrintRand(num));
          }

        if(numSets == 81)
        {
          printf("You have chosen to quit the program");
          return 0;
        }
        else if(numSets == 113)
        {
          printf("You have chosen to quit the program");
          return 0;        
        }
        else{
          printf("You have finished generating your sets of random numbers.\n");
          printf("Do you wish to continue or exit? Enter Q or q to quit or 1 to continue...\n");
          scanf("%d" , &exit);
          if(exit == 81){
            break;
          }
          else if(exit == 113){
            break;
          }
          else if(exit == 1){
            //how do i get the program to restart???
          }
          else //how do i restart this new loop to ask again for input??

        }

        }
```

Comment: what is exactly your problem ?

Comment: I'm having understanding what you're particularly stuck with?
You don't understand how to write main() so the behavior is like the described problem on the top?

Comment: @Dejan i cannot figure out how to structure it. that is what i have so far. i just updated it..i need help

Answer (score 2):

First, nowhere in the problem is it stated that the N sets you need to generate need to be different, so as long as you can generate 1 set, you can generate N sets.
Second, while you can't use arrays, 6 is a very small number so you can do it with 6 variables and some copy-pasting of code (it's not pretty).

For the algorithm itself I would keep it basic and do a "while I haven't generated 6 unique numbers, keep generating". It could in theory never halt (as you can keep generating random numbers you already have), but for homework it's good enough.

I hope that helps :D

Comment: `//how do i get the program to restart???`
By phrasing the algorithm differently. It's not "do stuff, and if the user asks, restart", it's "do this thing while the user hasn't told me to stop". Look at how `break` and `continue` work, I'm sure you can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `uint64_t` as an array of 8 bytes. With some bitwise operations it is solvable.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// using uint64_t as an array of bytes like
//   |---|---|6th|5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|
void PrintRand(int COUNT) {
  uint64_t nums = 0;
  unsigned num = 0;
  int i, j;
  int duplicate = 0;

  for (int cnt = 0; cnt < COUNT; cnt++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      do {
        num = (rand() % 53) + 1;

        // check if there is a duplicate
        for (duplicate = 0, j = 0; j < 6; j++)
          // retrieving the nth number from nums
          if (((nums >> (j * 8)) & 0xff) == num)
            duplicate = 1;

        if (duplicate) // if there is, then start again
          continue;

        // else save it to nums
        nums |= (uint64_t)(num << (i * 8));
        // and break out from do while loop
        break;
      } while (1);

      printf("%d ", num);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  srand(time(0)); 
  PrintRand(3);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
46 42 33 24 41 4 
15 6 25 9 11 52 
1 16 46 23 38 51
```